# handling exception for insert into select from

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert-into

### SCHEMA 1

I have table transaction table

```
create table TXN_HEADER
(
  txn_id         NUMBER(10) not null,
  txn_Date      date 
  product_id    NUMBER(10),
  company_id    NUMBER(10),
  dealer_id     NUMBER(10),
  tran_amt      number(10,2)
)
```

The above table having foreign key references to product.product_id and company.company_id.

This table having 5m rows

### SCHEMA 2

```
create table TXN_HEADER_REPORTS
(
  txn_id         NUMBER(10) not null,
  txn_Date      date 
  product_id    NUMBER(10),
  company_id    NUMBER(10),
  dealer_id     NUMBER(10),
  tran_amt      number(10,2)
)
```

here also we have the same constraints , having foreign key references to product.product_id and company.company_id.

in schema 2 we are trying to insert all the rows from schemea 1 to schema 2 in one shot, like this

```
begin 
  insert into TXN_HEADER_REPORTS (
  txn_id, txn_Date ,product_id,company_id   ,  dealer_id ,  tran_amt)
  select 
  txn_id, txn_Date ,product_id,company_id   ,  dealer_id ,  tran_amt
  from schema1.TXN_HEADER;
  commit;
exception   
  when others then 
    < ... procedure to log the errors > 
end;
```

now we are trying to execute the above procedure , and it failed due to foreign key constraint of one rows. But entire my transaction rollback. Actually i dont want to use cursor to process the rows one by one , at it takes long time. So i used to "insert into .. SElect from " but due to constraints of 1 row all my transaction not moved to schema2.txn_Extract_hdr.

Is there any way to trap only that failed and to process the other rows without terminating

Please advice ..

Comment: read this [Tom Kyte's answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1422998100346727312). It fully describes two ways of solving your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an error log table, and then use a single insert:

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'TXN_HEADER_REPORTS');

insert into TXN_HEADER_REPORTS ( txn_id, txn_Date ,product_id,company_id ,
  dealer_id , tran_amt)
select txn_id, txn_Date ,product_id,company_id , dealer_id , tran_amt
from schema1.TXN_HEADER
log errors into ERR$_TXN_HEADER_REPORTS reject limit unlimited;
```

Any rows that can't inserted will be recorded in the `ERR` table. Note that this is plain SQL, it doesn't need to be in a PL/SQL block.

[Read more in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#BGBEIACB).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your constraint.
Does your insert fail because the product_id and company_id don't exists in schema2?

In that case, it may be better to insert the missing company and product records before you insert records into TXN_HEADER_REPORTS of schema2.

```
insert into company   com_sch2
  (col1, col2, col2,...)
select col1, col2, col3, ...
from schema1.company com_sch1
where not exists (select 'x'
                  from company com2
                  where com2.company_id = com_sch1.company_id);
```

And the seem for the product table.